# Different label and legend values in Pie Chart using AChartEngine

Tags: achartengine

How can I set different label and legend values in Pie Chart using AChartEngine?

**Edit:** I'm using DefaultRenderer

**Edit2:** In the following image I present the current state and the desired result. Is it possible? If so, how?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both the series title, so they are the same.

Comment: No, that's not possible yet. However, you can create an issue and request this feature.

Comment: Thanks, I've created the feature request. Just one more question: is it possible to display the % symbol next to the percentage values ​​on the graph?

Comment: No, that's not possible either.